# Cant i store 4294967295 in unsigned int ? Int is 4 bytes on my machine

Tags: c, int

Why am i getting 0 ?? And compiler warning:

> format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 3 has type ‘long unsigned int’

Here is the code :

```
#include <stdio.h>

//function declerations...
int power(int base, int on);

int main(void) {
    printf("%d",power(2, sizeof(int)*8)-1);
    return 0;
}

int power(int base, int on) {
    int pf = 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < on; i++) {
        pf *= base;
    }
    return pf;
}
```

If int is 4 bytes on my system,i **guess** i should be able to store 4294967295 in **unsigned** int.

Comment: Learn about `limits.h`. Don't rely on assumptions (btw. you are wrong).

Comment: You forgot the other part of the iceberg: negative numbers

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre: An iceberg has 90% under water. signed integers have a(n almost) symmetrical range.

Comment: Sorry i mixed up signed and unsigned

Comment: See `INT_MAX` and `UINT_MAX`  from `limits.h`.

Comment: Your question is confused. Please correct it!

Comment: I am confused.I tried to store 2**32-1 in unsigned int and again its 0.Help ??

Comment: That is because `2**32` is out of range of the type, even before you subtract `1`.

Comment: @WeatherVane Indeed... So how can i deal with this.I want the power to return 4294967295.

Comment: `unsigned i = (unsigned)(4294967296ull - 1); printf("%u\n", i);` Result `4294967295`. Or work with 64-bit type anyway.

Comment: Besides which `4294967295` is not any power of one integer and another.

Comment: You don't print an **unsigned** `int`!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am back after long time (obviously) to this question, and I am not sure why everyone thinks OP meant to store `4294967296` when he wanted to store `4294967295` as asked in the question, maybe OP changed the question later, and no one bothered to re-answer. Now, back to question.

You can store `4294967295` in `unsigned int`, but the problem is in your printing, you are doing `printf("%d", 4294967295)` which means print `4294967295` as a `signed int`, but the number `4294967295` cannot be stored in `signed int`, so, narrowing conversion happens.

You need to print the `unsigned int` that you've got with `%u` rather than `%d`.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int power(int base, int pow);

int main(){
  printf("Size of unsigned int: %d\n", sizeof(unsigned int));
  unsigned int the_number = power(2, sizeof(int)*8)-1;
  printf("Wrongly printed: %d\n", the_number);
  printf("Correctly printed: %u\n", the_number);
  return 0;
}

int power(int base, int on) {
    int pf = 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < on; i++) {
        pf *= base;
    }
    return pf;
}
```

Comment: "Maybe OP changed the question later..." But is was *your* question, which you changed after the answers were received. Why would anyone "bother" to revisit to see if you asked the wrong question? It is bit much accepting your own answer.

Comment: @WeatherVane I am sorry, then stackoverflow is broken, as stackoverflow says "try to improve your questions", and, I did. Actually, question is not wrong, not at all, if it was wrong, it couldn't have an answer. And, as you can see, here, I answered it. So, if anyone encounters a problem like this, and saw this question with answer of any other guys that answered, he would be completely confused. This answer actually answers the "new" question. So, yeah. Thanks for that -1, give a -1 to right answer.

Comment: @WeatherVane And, as question changed, your and all other answers are "wrong". So, I get -1 because I 1. improve my question 2. answer the new question right.

Comment: With respect, I think it is your usage of SO that is broken. The idea of improving a question, is in reponse to queries and comments, so that it can be answered. But having received answers to the original question, changing it to a different question is not an improvement because it invalidated all the answers you had received. Expecting commenters to track your now different question and revise their answers is unreasonable. What you should have done, is to ask a new question: the one you intended to ask in the first place, perhaps making reference to this question, or delete this one first.

Comment: @WeatherVane Im sorry for going too offensive. But, I am frustrated that my account is banned from asking the stupid questions I asked earlier (like this one), and I want to improve them, in order for ban to be removed. And, I can't do that by asking another question because I am banned, I can edit, only. Any other solution?

Comment: I have never needed to do this, but you could try opening another account. Some people do this when they keep getting banned for asking troll questions, but I don't believe you are a troll. Your question was not stupid, but changing it to a different question, was.

Comment: Yeah, I guess I will make a new account. By the way, I wanted to ask you about your comment earlier, this one: `That is because 2**32 is out of range of the type, even before you subtract 1`. If that is true, why does my answer (the one that we are commenting on currently) works? Does it firstly take `2**32` as long int and then when I subtract 1 and put it in unsigned int it just converts it back to unsigned int? I mean, is that what happens? If so, why did you say the comment I just said above. Sorry for my awful English, I am tired and lazy to write correct/shiny words.

Comment: Please ask a new question.

Answer (score 4):

If your `int` or `unsigned int` is 32-bits, neither can store the value `4294967296` since this is `2**32` which would require a 64-bit type.

Even `uint32_t` can only store the max value `2**32 - 1` so your value is just `1` out of range.

But `int32_t` can store the max positive value `2**31 - 1` so the signed type is even further off.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming an `int` is 4 bytes and you have 8 bit bytes, then `int` is 32 bits wide.  Subsequently a `signed int` (if negatives are represented in 2's complement) has a range of -2147483648 to 2147483647 while `unsigned int` has a range of 0 to 4294967295.

The value 4294967296 in binary is `1 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000`.  This is 33 bits.  So 4294967296 is too big for this type.

Comment: That is not necessarily true. What if y byte has 9 bits? Or 16? Or there are padding bits? Or it uses a different encoding?

Comment: But how is it possible signed to be negative ??

Comment: Sorry,unsigned :(

Comment: I am just new to C

Comment: Nit-pick: here is no requirement to use all 32 bits ... There is also no need to make any assumptions about the range, as the implementation has to provide this information ready-to-use.