# %u expects argument of unsigned int but argument has type long int (4294967295)

Tags: c, byte

I am updating the question.Same case just another code.This could help you understand what i want.I am bad for explaining (mostly in English) so here is the code :

```
#include <stdio.h>
unsigned int power(unsigned int base, unsigned int on);

int main(void) {
    printf("\n%d\n",sizeof(int));
    printf("\n%u\n",4294967295);
    return 0;
}
```

## Compiler Warning:

> csilssRanges.c: In function ‘main’:
>   csilssRanges.c:16:5: warning: format ‘%u’ expects argument of type ‘unsigned int’, but argument 2 has type ‘long int’ [-Wformat=]
>        printf("%u",4294967295);

## Output:

> 4
>
> 4294967295

I am trying to understand why am i getting the compiler warning.I hope i am explaining well what i want.And i think the question is more reasonable now.And not duplicate to my recent question.

Comment: What did you do to understand this? Did you read the chapter about number representation  in your C book? Did you look at Wikipedia at least? Your code invokes undefined behaviour, there could be daemons flying out of your nose or your optical drive serving pizza.

Comment: Recently [answered question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39880560/cant-i-store-4294967295-in-unsigned-int-int-is-4-bytes-on-my-machine/39880761#39880761). Asked by the very same.

Comment: As was said before, `2**31` ***cannot be represented by a 32-bit signed integer.***

Comment: @WeatherVane: CV as dup. Thanks for pointing out, I really should have noticed as I commented on both. Still, I like one answer here.

Comment: @Olaf yes the question has evolved into a better discussion.

Comment: @WeatherVane I wanted to ask how can i print **unsigned int** and store 2**31 in unsigned int ?

Comment: @Olaf You dont like me using stackoverflow or what ?? Becuase you argue on all of my questions with me... Please be polite.

Comment: @MuhamedCicak: Of course, it is the others' fault, not your's. One aspect of a good programmer is that he first verifies it is not his fault. Oh, and paranoia is never a good advisor.

Comment: @Olaf Firstly i am not a good programmer.That's why i am here.To get help and learn.Not to argue with someone...

Comment: @MuhamedCicak: You missed the point of my comment. You will never become a good programmer if you don't try. Which means first think about advice applying common sense and doing reserach on your own. **And** listen to arguments. Non knowing is ok, but _willful ignorance_ Is a very bad attitude. So, and as you don't want to argue, the solution is simple: don't argue! You are not obliged to reply to a comment. Anyway, I don't really care if you believe it or not, but I tried to help you advance. But I don't force you into, you just have to live with the results (i.e. close-votes - not just mine)

Comment: @Olaf That's true, i agree.If i don't try i cant make it. But what makes you think i didn't ? And i didn't understand your answer,i saw you tried to answer. But i did not understand your answer. And yeah :) Still i could not understand the answer.I wish someone can explain in details. Nevermind. We shouldn't argue, as you said :)

Comment: And how can i close the question ? I am not sure.And sorry for all the argue.And thanks on your advices.

Comment: @Muhamed Cicak to put the value `2**31` into `unsigned int` you can do it like this: `unsigned i = 2147483648u;` and print it like this `printf("%u\n", i);`

Comment: @WeatherVane Thank you.I recently changed the question.I googled and find out just what you said.I dont know if it is allowed to change question entirely.But i changed it because it was duplicate.Do you know the answer of current version of question ?

Comment: Just like my last comment, but with `4294967295u` or print directly with `printf("%u\n", 4294967295u);`

Comment: Yap ! :) If you want write it as answer.I will make it **the** answer.

Comment: I cannot, the question has been closed.

Comment: Cant i open it ? :) I am new to stackoverflow,so i dont really know that.Am i able to renew it in some way ??

Comment: I do have the rep to re-open the question but that would be bad form if my purpose is to gain more rep myself. Just be happy with the comments.

Comment: Ok.I appreciate your help :)

Answer (score 2):

Since the correct answer is *still* missing here, I'll chime in.

Your code when running with 32-bit integers, will produce undefined behaviour. That means that literally anything could happen. The C standard (the "rules" for what the C language **is**) specifically says that putting a number that is too big into a signed integer value results in undefined behaviour. As such your compile could do anything.

Most compilers on most architectures will store signed integers using 2's compliment. In that case the sensible thing to do is to 'overflow' back down to the negative value (look up 2's compliment addition and test it on the largest positive value).

However, this **does not** have to be the case. Another valid output would be:

2

4

...

1073741824

No thanks, number too big. Executing `rm -rf /`. Have a good day.

While that would be a lot of work for a compiler to implement, it would **still** be a valid C compiler.

To print bigger values, use bigger types. In C99 and later you can use `stdint.h` to get access to `int64_t` which is 64-bits wide and can happily store 4 billion. Printing such a number is done with `printf("%" PRId64, X)` instead of `printf("%d", X)`. To declare such a literal you would need to use the L or LL endings. As such `printf("%" PRId64 "\n", 4294967295ULL)` **should** print the value you'd expect.

Comment: I'm surprised that you suggest PRI to print a unsigned long long, which should use ull. Or use a cast to uint64_t.

Comment: +1 Just that: It is actually not the compiler dion that behaviour, but the hardware/CPU, the compiler just does not emit extra code, as that would be nonsense. FYI: such undefined behaviour can (and will where it comes in handy) be exploited by modern compilers. Especially gcc is well known to be very agressive and therefore e.g. has some bad reputation with programmers who are used to more forgiving compilers who don't strictly follow the standard. The embedded field is such an example. The obvious problem is that they generate less optimised code.

Comment: That was a demonstration of how to print an int64_t, even though the ull is not such a value and PRIu64 is better, the code is not meant run, it is meant as a demonstration. @Olaf exactly why I pointed it out, I've run into weird non-standard behaviour before (my favourite was a school project from a friend that crashed every other input, but would actually dump relevant lines of the standard to stdout whenever undefined behaviour was compiled)

Comment: @2501: Actually it is `llu`. But yes, `PRId64` is for the **signed** `int64_t`. To get such a constant, the macro `INT64_C(4294967295)` shall be used (no size-tag on the value!).

Comment: @LambdaBeta: see my comment above. And good attitude to strictly follow the standard. (Although there are areas like OS or bare-metal embedded where one has to "bend" the rules  sometimes. But that requires good knowledge about the implementation details).

Comment: @Olaf Yes I switched them around, the printf format specifier must be in order: llu. C is slightly inconsistent since integer constants may be defined as 123ull or 123llu. You probably meant UINT64_C(). A cast should also be fine. It depends on personal preference.

Comment: @2501: No, I meant `INT64_C` A cast can be problematic (not likely here, but in general). Also the macro is a clear statement you want a 64 bit (or larger) constant, while `long long` can be 128 bits. This becomes more problematic for e.g. `long`/`int` vs. `int32_t`. On 2nd thought the cast might actually be worth a try (just omit the suffix), because a variadic function cannot  check type compatibility. Yes, that's a minefield.

Comment: @Olaf Yeah I agree to use the macro. I would probably prefer a const variable as the macro looks ugly.

Comment: @Olaf Detail: `INT64_C(4294967295)` returns a type of `int_least64_t` which may differ from the optional `int_64_t`, the matching type for `PRId64`.  Best if OP simply used `printf("%llu\n", 4294967295ULL)` or `printf("%" PRId64 "\n", (int64_t) 4294967295)`

Comment: @chux: from my 2nd post about that subject: "... Also the macro is a clear statement you want a 64 bit (or larger) constant ..." and the rest. As far as I understand the standard, it will eventually yield a type of the exact size if such a type exists. As we already presume `int64_t` exists, it should yield that type, resp. the corresponding standard type. It just will yield a wider type if there is no 64 bit type, but a wider one.

Comment: No one seems to answer asked question here... I am asking first of all Can i store 4294967295 in 32 bits (**UNSIGNED INT**) ??  Second of all how to print unsigned int ??

Answer (score -2):

2^31 overflows a 4-byte signed integer. It 'wraps around' to -(2^31).

Comment: No, it does not! Please provide a link to the standard where it defines that signed integer overflow wraps.

Comment: The link is my 30 years of programming in C, my BS in Engineering, and my MS in Computer Science.

Comment: Argumentum ad verecundiam. Sorry, but that is no reference and I will not conter with the same. The code simply invokes undefined behaviour. Signed integer overflow is one of the **explicitly** mentioned examples in the standard. Oh, I even have a reference: see 3.4.3p3 in the standard.

Comment: Say all the Latin you want. Man does not live by standards alone. Have a nice day.

Comment: @Olaf Standards are nice and fine … are there any commonly used compilers on commonly used platforms which do not assume this overflowing behavior?

Comment: The section on [Vulnerabilities Resulting from Undefined Behaviors](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=2086870) goes into why compilers have evolved to take advantage of `int` overflow.  So @bwoebi , compliers today take advantage of such code to the chagrin of season coders.

Comment: @bwoebi: You'd be surprised how agressive modern compilers optimise such code.

Comment: @bwoebi a good compiler will emit code that does *something* reasonable when given non-standard behaviour at runtime, not just throw tomatoes..

Comment: @WeatherVane: You mean I buying that daemon-defense tower was nonsense? How do I get this out of my nose?

Comment: @bwoebi: Re. compilers: Have a look at custom CPUs an DSPs. One (intended) behaviour is saturation. Also there are non 2s complement platforms.

Comment: This is really fun but let us agree that the OP did not ask about standards or vulnerabilities or optimization. He simply asked why he got a specific set of output for a specific set of input. Thanks for the downvotes anyway.